# Why can't I get the iframe to open when it's inside a loop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops, iframe

I have this code that should loop through an array of video and get the key under the specified conditions in the if conditional but the iframe wont open, the modal is opening but the iframe is not. When I console log the key, it displays it perfectly and without the looping, the iframe is showing, is there a way I can loop and get the key i need and put it in the iframe.

```js
import axios from "axios";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const Modal = ({ closeModal, id, name }) => {
  const [video, setVideo] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(
        `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/${id}/videos?api_key=<<api_key>>&language=en-US`
      )
      .then((response) => {
        setVideo(response.data.results);
        // console.log(response.data);
      });
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="bg-black/60 fixed top-0 left-0 w-full h-screen   ">
      <div className="flex h-screen justify-center items-center">
        <div className="p-4 w-full max-w-2xl h-full md:h-auto">
          <div className="relative bg-transparent rounded-lg shadow ">
            <div className="flex justify-between items-start p-4 rounded-t border-b">
              <h3 className="text-xl font-semibold text-gray-200 ">{name}</h3>
              <button
                onClick={() => closeModal(false)}
                type="button"
                className="text-gray-400 bg-transparent hover:bg-gray-200 hover:text-gray-900 rounded-lg text-sm p-1.5 ml-auto inline-flex items-center dark:hover:bg-gray-600 dark:hover:text-white"
                data-modal-toggle="defaultModal"
              >
                <svg
                  className="w-5 h-5"
                  fill="currentColor"
                  viewBox="0 0 20 20"
                  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                >
                  <path
                    fillRule="evenodd"
                    d="M4.293 4.293a1 1 0 011.414 0L10 8.586l4.293-4.293a1 1 0 111.414 1.414L11.414 10l4.293 4.293a1 1 0 01-1.414 1.414L10 11.414l-4.293 4.293a1 1 0 01-1.414-1.414L8.586 10 4.293 5.707a1 1 0 010-1.414z"
                    clipRule="evenodd"
                  ></path>
                </svg>
              </button>
            </div>

            <div className="p-6 space-y-6">
              {video &&
                video.map((item, i) => {
                  if (
                    item?.type == "Trailer" &&
                    item?.name == "Official Trailer"
                  ) {
                    <iframe
                      width="560"
                      height="315"
                      src={`https://www.youtube.com/embed/${item?.key}`}
                      title="YouTube video player"
                      frameBorder="0"
                      allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
                      allowFullScreen
                    ></iframe>;
                    console.log(item?.key);
                  }
                })}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Modal;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that you are not returning the `iframe` while looping.

```
{video &&
                video.map((item, i) => {
                  if (
                    item?.type == "Trailer" &&
                    item?.name == "Official Trailer"
                  ) {
                    return <iframe
                      width="560"
                      height="315"
                      src={`https://www.youtube.com/embed/${item?.key}`}
                      title="YouTube video player"
                      frameBorder="0"
                      allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
                      allowFullScreen
                    ></iframe>;
                    console.log(item?.key);
                  }
                })}
```

OR, better if you want to skip `return` keyword, simple replace your curly braces `{}` with round brackets `()`. Round brackets serve as a return statement.
`someArray.map(x => (<iframe>.....</iframe>))`

The reason you are getting the value in `console.log()` is that the `.map()` function is still working, like its looping through, but its just that it isn't returning anything to UI. So all of your calculations inside it would still run normally.

Comment: Thanks, it worked...such a rookie error.